# Checking a Proof of a Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Theorem 1.2 of Bennett and Skinner (Canad. J. Math., 2004) asserts that the Diophantine equation $x^{p} - 4y^{p} = z^{2}$ is unsolvable for every prime $p \geq 7.$
The following is a possible proof (from an arXiv author) that Fermat's Last Theorem is a consequence of this theorem, i.e., proof that if there exist integers $x, y, z > 0$ such that $(x, y) = 1$ and $x^{p} + y^{p} = z^{p},$ then there exist integers $a, b, c > 0$ such that $(a, b)=1$ and $a^{p} - 4b^{p} = c^{2}$.

Take a prime
$p \geq 7.$
We will prove Fermat's Last Theorem in the form:
*Take integers $x, y, z > 0$.
If
$(x, y) = 1,$
then
$x^{p} + y^{p} \neq z^{p}$.*

We argue by contradiction.
By the equation
$x^{p} + y^{p} = z^{p}$
there is a rational
$0 < r < 1$
such that
$$x^{p} = rz^{p}\ \ \mbox{and}\ \ y^{p} = (1-r)z^{p},$$
so that
$$r^{2} - r + \dfrac{(xy)^{p}}{z^{2p}} = 0,$$
and hence
$$r = \dfrac{1 + \sqrt{1 - 4(xy)^{p}/z^{2p}}}{2}\ \ \mbox{or}\ \  \dfrac{1 - \sqrt{1 - 4(xy)^{p}/z^{2p}}}{2}.$$
Therefore,
the difference
$1 - 4(xy)^{p}/z^{2p} \geq 0$
is to be a perfect square.
But since
$$1 - \dfrac{4(xy)^{p}}{z^{2p}} = \dfrac{z^{2p} - 4(xy)^{p}}{z^{2p}},$$
since
$z^{2p}$
is a perfect square,
and since if $z^{2p} = 4(xy)^{p}$
then from the equation
$x^{p} + y^{p} = z^{p}$
we have
$x = y$
that leads to a contradiction,
so there is an integer
$c > 0$
such that
$$z^{2p} - 4(xy)^{p} = c^{2}.$$
On choosing
$$a := z^{2}\ \ \mbox{and}\ \ b := xy$$
we have
$$a, b > 0\ \ \mbox{and}\ \ a^{p} - 4b^{p} = c^{2}.$$
Moreover,
because
$(x, y) = 1$
and
$x^{p} + y^{p} = z^{p},$
we have
$(x, y) = (y, z) = (x, z) = 1,$
whence
$$(a, b) = 1.$$
But the existence of such
$a, b, c$
contradicts Theorem 1.2 of Bennett and Skinner [1].

Comment: $$z^{2p} - 4(xy)^{p} = (x^p+y^p)^2- 4(xy)^{p}= (x^p-y^p)^2$$ so your $c=x^p-y^p$ ;)

Comment: Are $a$ and $c$ relatively prime?

Comment: The key question is: Does the proof of Theorem 1.2 make use of any of Wile's results to prove Fermat's Last Theorem? If so, the answer to your question is no.

Comment: @Genomeme: "the answer to your question is no": What question? Whose question?

Comment: Good point. I suppose a question was not asked. My point was that the proof may not in fact be a valid proof.

Comment: To highlight the excellent comment of @N.S.: the whole proof in the question can be simplified to: “as $$(x^p + y^p)^2 - 4(xy)^p = (x^p - y^p)^2$$ (a purely algebraic identity), we have $$x^p + y^p = z^p \implies (z^2)^p - 4(xy)^p = (x^p - y^p)^2$$ which is a solution to $a^p - 4b^p = c^2$.”

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your proof looks OK to me. But don't rush to publish $-$ it seems to me that Theorem 1.2 (available at [this link](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/BS.pdf)) depends on the Taniyama–Shimura–Weil conjecture (or the modularity theorem, as it should now be called), just like Wiles' proof of Fermat's Last Theorem did.

So your proof is $-$ roughly speaking $-$ using a consequence of Fermat's Last Theorem to prove Fermat's Last Theorem.